# Is IP masquerade and Network Address Port Translation(NAPT) the same?

Tags: computer-networks, ip

Is IP masquerade and Network Address Port Translation(NAPT) the same? I'm not sure whether it is the same thing or not but I realized the mechanism is almost the same where both IP masquerade and NAPT changes TCP/UDP port and many-to-one relation is allowed:multiple private addresses share one global IP address.
If it is different which part is IP masquerade and NAPT is different?

Answer (score 1):

IP masquerade is the same as NAPT and the only difference is that when NAPT is used in Linux, it is called IP masquerade. The mechanism is the same, it's just the place where the technology is implemented is different.

Comment: In Linux, NAPT is called IP Masquerade for historical reasons.